# /dev/sda3 is not showing in one vm but the same is shown in another vm.

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, vmware, centos7

I am new to linux admin activities. Why /dev/sda3 is shown in one vm. but it doesnt show in another vm. Not sure where to go and check this. can someone please help.

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009a61a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    33554431    16264192   8e  Linux LVM
```

From another VM:

```
[root@inches-rmdev01 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009a61a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    33554431    16264192   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        33554432   104857599    35651584   8e  Linux LVM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a utility that shows unpartitioned space as well e.g cfdisk

e.g I have partitioned an 8GB sd card to have three partitions. Total size of these three partitions is less than 8GB as shown by **fdisk**:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 8068 MB, 8068792320 bytes
249 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1020 cylinders, total 15759360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4c2671d0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *       32776       65543       16384    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2           65544     7438343     3686400   83  Linux
/dev/sdc3            2048       32775       15364   a2  Unknown
```

With **cfdisk** we can see the unpartitioned space as well:

```
$ sudo cfdisk -P s /dev/sdc
Partition Table for /dev/sdc

               First       Last
 # Type       Sector      Sector   Offset    Length   Filesystem Type (ID) Flag
-- ------- ----------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------------------- ----
   Pri/Log           0        2047*     0#       2048*Free Space           None
 3 Primary        2048*      32775*     0       30728*Unknown (A2)         None
 1 Primary       32776*      65543*     0       32768*W95 FAT32 (LBA) (0C) Boot
 2 Primary       65544*    7438343*     0     7372800*Linux (83)           None
   Pri/Log     7438344*   15759359*     0     8321016*Free Space           None
```

Here you can see that there is free space available at both start and end of the disk.

Some graphical utilities, e.g **GParted** can also show the unpartitioned space

```
$ sudo gparted /dev/sdc
```

[image: gparted showing unpartitioned/free space on disk]